# Tensor flow word2vec for multiple files input

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word2vec

I am trying to train a word2vec skip-gram model on some in-house dataset. I am following tensorflow [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) tutorial. The dataset has sentences so I modified generate_batch function and stored (batch,label) in csv files. Since the data is large, these files are divided into part-files. I need to change the tf.session part of the code to accommodate these multiple files. I can't load all files at once because of memory constraints. Here is my code for tf.session:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob

folder_files =  glob.glob("word2vecIndexes")

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    print('Initialized')
    for i in len(folder_files):
        indexes_data = getData(folder_files[i])
        average_loss = 0
        index=0
        length_train = len(indexes_data)
        check_range = int(length_train/batch_size)+1
        print(check_range)
        for step in range(check_range):
            print("....."+step)
            batch_data, batch_labels = generate_batch(index, batch_size, length_train)
            index = index+batch_size
            feed_dict = {train_dataset : batch_data, train_labels : batch_labels}
            _, l = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            average_loss += l
            if step % 2000 == 0:
              if step > 0:
                average_loss = average_loss / 2000
              # The average loss is an estimate of the loss over the last 2000 batches.
              print('Average loss at step %d: %f' % (step, average_loss))
              average_loss = 0
    final_embeddings = normalized_embeddings.eval()
    ## save as textFile ##
    np.savetxt('~/final_embedding_dic.txt',final_embeddings)
    ## save as tensorflow variable ##
    saver.save(self._session,opts.save_path + "model")enter code here`
```

I am new to tensorflow, so I am confused if "final_embeddings" will represent trained embeddings using all files or it gets initialized at every iteration and is trained on that part file only. Is there any optimized way to run this?

Comment: there are decent tutorials on the official site, take a look at queuerunners and https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data

Comment: @dv3 Thanks. I will definitely look into it.